# How to sync my iTunes library to my iPhone while still using iCloud Music Library for Apple Music?

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-music

Is it possible for me to keep iCloud Music Library turned on so I can actually use Apple Music (save tracks and playlists to the My Music playlist) while also maintaining the ability to sync any music I acquire the old-fashioned way (downloads, CDs, etc) and add to my iTunes library?

It's so damn annoying to have to turn on and off iCloud Music Library just to be able to sync music to my phone while using Apple Music.

Comment: I've looked and looked and can't find anyone saying it's possible, but putting up a bounty in a fit of blind optimism!

Comment: I've waited months for this problem to be solved.. But I'm just getting tired.. Thinking to cancel Apple Music service..

Comment: @FidelEduardoLópez i have had a ticket open with Apple for over a month.  Last week I opened another one.  No one at Apple even seems to be able to confirm if you should be able to do this or not.  Isn't this Syncing 101?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204925 here is the Apple post that implies it is possible.

Comment: Apple Music seemed great till I realised this issue meant I couldn't add any music bought elsewhere, in the end after research decided I had to cancel Apple Music entirely. Odd behaviour from apple, send like a perfect way to sabotage apple music as a product.

Comment: I am abandoning Apple, iPhone and iTunes and buying a Google Pixel because of this. Ten years of iTunes library curation destroyed.

Comment: Any update on this ?

Comment: @Max, I stopped using Apple Music after the 3 month trial period and switched back to Spotify. Unless something has changed, I think it's safe to say that Apple will not be supporting syncing over the cable, only through the iTunes -> Apple Music server -> iOS device library method.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think there is a way to do this, but it is not my preferred method.

When you have iCloud Music Library turned on for your iPhone or iOS device, you will also need to make sure it is turned on for your iTunes library on the desktop. When you do so Apple automatically uploads your iTunes library to iCloud. Then, your iTunes library shows up on your iOS device. If you want to save those tracks locally, you must choose to do so within Apple Music on the device itself.

Basically, Apple has done away with the idea of syncing your music locally through a USB cable, you must do it over the air via your data connection or WiFi. Kind of stupid that it has to go through Apple's iCloud servers first and then back to your device...

Comment: This doesn't address the issue though. When you enable iCloud music library, you can't manage _what_ gets synced, which is the point of the question. The only benefit of iCloud music library that I and OP want is to be able to save music from Apple Music to a device.

Comment: Heh, I am OP. I agree that this isn't quite the solution that we were looking for. I don't see any other way of doing it. Unless Apple revises how users can sync their library to their devices (which I strongly doubt they will, because they're Apple and they know best). You will see your entire library on your device (in the 'cloud') and you can choose what to save locally... I believe you can show only saved items on your device as well if that helps.

Comment: Haha I didn't even notice.

Comment: Thanks!!! I switched computers and for months haven't known why my phone wasn't getting updated. So frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, this is a huge pain to manage and it has been bugging me ever since I turned it on.

That being said, I just tried this and it worked:

- Turn off iCloud Music Library on your iOS Device
- Plug into your computer and sync playlists
- Turn on iCloud Music Library on your iOS Device

It will not delete the playlists that are already there; they will be merged with your iCloud Playlists.

Comment: This is only a temporary solution. Once you try to sync over the USB cable again with iCloud Music Library turned on, you will not be allowed to do so.

Comment: This does work, but the actual contents of your playlists no longer sync across your devices.  all this gives is you a one time clone of your iTunes playlists.

Comment: I can't answer over here coz I'm new to this community, but this worked for me. `Sign out from your iTunes and you'll find the option to sync music and videos. Then go to your music section and select sync entire music library and BOOM!!` it will work.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this? (Inside red square)

[image]

You can group your music inside a playlist and only select that playlist to sync from the `Playlist` on bottom.

I have not tried it yet because I have that Apple Music iCloud Library problem and can't save music offline.

Let me know if that helped you!

Comment: The problem is, when iCloud music library is enabled, you get none of that when you click on music. You get a blank screen saying "iCloud music library is on." Nothing else!

Comment: I have mentioned that I am not able to test this. Down vote was not necessary. Hope you find someone that can help you ;)

Comment: Downvote was not necessary? You're just putting misinformation here. This answer *should* be downvoted.

Comment: Thanks for sticking onto my answer. You can simply downvote it ;)